# onfocus for form input to change border colour?

Tags: html, css, forms, onfocus

I'm trying to add a colour border to a form field when a user clicks on the field, I'm good at html and javascript, with a bit of php, but my css is actually quite poor. The  code for the form etc is below. I would really appreciate if anyone could direct or help me.
CODE:

```
<form id="search" action="http://www.bkslap.com/search/results.php" id="cse-search-box">
<input name="q" type="text" id="q" autocomplete="on" size="56"  style="color:#ccc;" maxlength="128" id="q"
onblur="this.value = this.value || this.defaultValue; this.style.color = '#ccc';"
onfocus="this.value=''; this.style.color = '#9933FF';"
value="Search" />
</form>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It'd probably be cleaner to add and subtract a class with the onBlur and onFocus.  Then in the css class you could have:

```
.focus {
background: yellow;
color: #000;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border.asp) for more information on the border properties. (with apologies to those who hate w3schools, but it's a reasonable place for this type of reference).

http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/focus_pseudo_class/

Comment: Agreed with moving style and javascript possibly to includes.  Sure you will take a bit more time but it will save you later lots of pain.

Comment: Great! You could vote me up, then, or check the box next to my answer. Or why not both?

Comment: just an fyi... when I added a border to my text fields they seemed to shrink compared to the other fields in the form.  I had to add `padding:1px; height:21px;` with the border so that everything stayed the same size and stuff.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin, that's because the borders take up space, so when you add them, more space is being taken up. Try adding a border to the un-focused state that is the same color as the background. Then the hover will just change the color of the border, not changing the space the element uses

Answer (score 12):

Just use css for outline color like so:

```css
.class {
    outline-color:#FF0;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer across all browsers. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp ;) There is a note for IE8 support - you must specify DOCTYPE.

Comment: best and the most direct answer, thanks so much

Answer (score 7):

you can use the `:focus` pseudoclass `#q:focus {border:red 1px solid;}` but as you can see here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html it's not supported by ie 7 and below. To achieve cross browser compatibility you can use jquery and the following code

```
$('#q').focus(function() {
    $('#q').css('border','1px solid red');
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me that how do I make the input field previous border color when I click outside the input field.

Answer (score 2):

```css
input:not([type="button"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):hover, input:not([type="button"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):focus, textarea:hover, textarea:focus, select:hover, select:focus 
{    
    border:2px solid #1b2a44;    
    outline:none;
}
.form-control{
padding:5px;
background-color:#f7f7f7;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <label>TextBox 1:</label><input type="text" class="form-control">
  <label>TextBox 2:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control">
```

Comment: please give provide some description

Comment: you can shortly  use input:focus{ here css  of outline what is used } same as you can use for select, textarea

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Carl-Michael Hughes is what finally worked for me! outline-color is the only way to set the focus "border" color. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
input:not([type="button"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):hover, input:not([type="button"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):focus, textarea:hover, textarea:focus, select:hover, select:focus {
    border-color: #81256f;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Use this CSS. This will do the job for you. With the above CSS i achieved the following output:
[image]

Hope this helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using inline style like this and would even recommend wiring up the events via javascript/jquery but...

You can set background color with object.style.borderColor.  Color is only the font color.

The css markup in shorthand is just 'border' or specifically if you want to set border color from css it is 'border-color'.  In javascript that turns to this.style.borderColor.